# Interval stop and reset by clicking another button during an interval

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, settimeout

I want to implement the interval in which the number increases when the button is clicked.

There are multiple buttons and one element with increasing number.

The problem is, if I click another button during an interval, I can't stop the interval that was already in progress.

Please help me.

**HTML**

```
<ul> 
  <li><a href="javascript:;" class="btn" data-length="3">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" class="btn" data-length="8">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" class="btn" data-length="5">3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="counter">0</div>
```

**JS**

```js
const interval = (e) => {
  setTimeout(() => { 
    $('.counter').html(e)
  }, 500 * e);
}

$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      length = $this.data('length');

  for (let i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
    (function(e){
        interval(e)
    })(i)
  }
})
```

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/bnzLrg03/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `setTimeout` to a variable and then use `clearTimeout` to remove the timer from it.

```
const interval = (e) => {
  window.sT = setTimeout(() => { 
    $('.counter').html(e)
  }, 500 * e);
}
```

.. and this way you can clear the timer by using `clearTimeout(sT)`

Piecing all together

```
const interval = (e) => {
  window.sT = setTimeout(() => { 
    $('.counter').html(e)
  }, 500 * e);
}

$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  if(window.sT) clearTimeout(window.sT);
  var $this = $(this),
      length = $this.data('length');

  for (let i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
    (function(e){
        interval(e)
    })(i)
  }
})
```

However, I'm really not sure why you are looping over the `length` value here. I'd suggest using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Updating the solution with a `setInterval` usage and removed unnecessary variables

```
const interval = (e) => {
  let i = 1;
  window.sT = setInterval(() => { 
    $('.counter').html(i++)
    if(i > e) clearInterval(sT);
  }, 1000);
}

$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  if(window.sT) clearTimeout(window.sT);
  interval($(this).data('length'))
})
```

```js
const interval = (e) => {
  let i = 1;
  window.sT = setInterval(() => { 
    $('.counter').html(i++)
    if(i > e) clearInterval(sT);
  }, 1000);
}

$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  if(window.sT) clearTimeout(window.sT);
  interval($(this).data('length'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" class="btn" data-length="3">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" class="btn" data-length="8">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" class="btn" data-length="5">3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="counter">0</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

But it's still not being clearTimeout. TT

Will it improve if I make it an setInterval?

I'll try it!

Comment: Oh, interval was the answer!
Thank you so much!!